# Apache proxy, ws vs. wss and https

Tags: apache2, reverse-proxy

O-tree is a web-based software that uses websockets. I have it working on `http://server.example:81` and I want it to be in `https://server.example`. It almost works with

```
<Location />
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
    ProxyPass "ws://localhost:81/"
    ProxyPass "http://localhost:81/"
</Location>
```

However I got an error about `GET wss://server.example/create_demo_session`. Hence I suppose I should somehow say "no https for ws, please". If I let out `X-Forwarded-Proto`-part, then the front page gives links to `http://server.example` instead of `https://server.example`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can differentiate between WSS and HTTPS requests and do different proxying for them.  This is the rule I used when [I built a music player with a Raspberry Pi](https://blog.ostermiller.org/raspberry-pi-music-player/):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*) ws://localhost:81/$1 [P,L]
RewriteRule /(.*) http://localhost:81/$1 [P,L]
```

The `RewriteCond` tests if the request is `wss:` and forwards those requests over `ws:`, other requests use the `http:` proxy rule.

Comment: I accepted this, as this is almost perfect now. For some reason I had to put this inside `<Directory>` block, but that is something related to our base settings in RHEL servers.


I must use ...myserver/demo as address to get this working; otherwise it shows `GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found` in the Otree output.